# How to print time as #inst

Tags: clojure

It's easy to read a date literal:

```
(read-string "#inst \"2012\"")
        ;;; ⇒ #inst "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00"
```

How can I output a date as a `#inst...` literal?

This does not work:

```
(pr-str (clj-time.core/now))
        ;;; ⇒ "#<DateTime 2013-07-09T17:26:30.058Z>"

(read-string (pr-str (clj-time.core/now)))
        ;;; ⇒ <err>
        ;;;   RuntimeException Unreadable form  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:219)
```

Comment: I'm using clojure 1.5.1, entering the following in the REPL `(java.util.Date.)` prints `#inst "2013-07-09T18:05:53.231-00:00"`.

Comment: Note that `clj-time.core/now` is a DateTime object, which is Joda.

Comment: Oh, I see, my mistake. Thanks :). What about converting `DateTime` to `java.util.Date` and then printing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you read in an `#inst` literal, by default, a `java.util.Date` instance is created. These have a method defined for `print-method` (a multimethod responsible for printed representations of objects) in the `clojure.instant` namespace (the relevant fragment of the 1.5.1 source is [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/clj/clojure/instant.clj#L169)).

clj-time uses the `DateTime` type from Joda-Time, which has no custom `print-method` method set up. This makes sense, since having a `print-method` which produces a representation which doesn't round-trip is rarely desirable. In order for it to round-trip, you'd have to use a non-standard `#inst` reader. To achieve that, if you're reading edn data, you can use `clojure.edn/read` (or `read-string`) passing the appropriate reader in as documented in its docstring:

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])

(edn/read {:readers {'inst your-inst-reader}} rdr)
```

When using clj-time, `your-inst-reader` will be something like `#(clj-time.format/parse some-formatter %)`. You can then provide a matching `print-method` definition following the example of `clojure.instant`. (Or you could just provide the `print-method` definition and remember that you won't get perfect roundtripping; clj-time provides very convenient coercion functions -- see below -- so this might be ok.)

Alternatively you could print and read `java.util.Date` instances and convert them to and from `DateTime`s; there are functions for doing that in `clj-time.coerce`.

Comment: I ended up coercing to java.util.Date.

Comment: I've asked upstream if it is possible to provide a general solution: https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/issues/93

Comment: Wait, so how do I print a timestamp as `#inst "YYYY-MM..."`?